# Прикрепить onchange к select jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

Я хочу, чтобы при изменении `select` - удалялся элемент. Код для удаления я написал и он работает, но я не могу прикрепить `onchange` к `select`.

Все эти селекты должны быть прикреплены к `onchange`:

```
$('select[name=status]').attr('onchange', 'deleteFuel()');
$('select[name=make]').attr('onchange', 'deleteFuel()');
$('select[name=serie]').attr('onchange', 'deleteFuel()');
function deleteFuel(){
$("span:contains(Тип горючего: )").closest('li').remove();
}
```

HTML одного из `select` без `option`:

```
<select name="serie" class="form-control select2-hidden-accessible" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
</select>
```

Comment: `$('select[name=status]').change(() => deleteFuel())`

Comment: @entithat не работает.

Comment: добавьте хтмл еще

Comment: @entithat Работает, спасибо. Просто кэш забыл почистить